# When I run sudo -i or sudo su I get an error

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, 22.04, su

Error when running `sudo su`:

```
su: failed to execute /bi: No such file or directory
```

Error when running `sudo -i`:

```
sudo: /bi: command not found
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: It sounds like you have somehow corrupted the root user's login shell entry in the password database - what  does `getent passwd root` return?

Comment: @steeldriver root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned from [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)'s deleted answer that I corrupted the root user's login shell entry in the password database and I know how to fix that:

```
sudo vipw
```

Then replace `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bi` with:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```